# MySQL - PhpMyadmin - Create Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, ddl, create-table

I can´t understand why this query is not working to create this table structure in PHPMyAdmin.

I always receive this error message:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'MAX),
>       FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCES form (Id) )' at line 4

```
CREATE TABLE form(
    Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(500),
    Is_Active BIT,
    Is_Trash BIT,
    Date_Created DATETIME
);
CREATE TABLE form_data(
    Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    form_id INT,
    formdata VARCHAR(MAX),
    FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCES form (Id)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`varchar(max)` is MS SQL Server's syntax.  MySQL doesn't have an equivalent, so you'll just have to use a very long size. Additionally, once you'll solve this problem, you'll encounter a problem where `form_data.form_id` is not of the the same type as `form.id` (one is unsigned and the other isn't), so it cannot reference it. In short:

```
CREATE TABLE form_data(
    Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    form_id INT UNSIGNED, -- Second issue
    formdata VARCHAR(4000), -- First issue 
    FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCES form (Id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems in table `form_data`:

1. type of form_id, it should be INT UNSIGNED to match type of Id type of table `form`
2. Using formdata VARCHAR(MAX), you should change MAX to real integer, 255 for example

Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE form(
    Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(500),
    Is_Active BIT,
    Is_Trash BIT,
    Date_Created DATETIME
);
CREATE TABLE form_data(
    Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    form_id INT UNSIGNED,
    formdata VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCES form (Id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error come from :

```
formdata VARCHAR(MAX),
```

Change MAX to a value.